# How to implement a maven repo?

Tags: http, maven-repository

I'm desperately looking for documentation regarding which endpoints should a maven repo serve.

I want to create my own http server (I think it's http, at least) that proxies maven central but makes some extra validations and fires some extra actions, and well... I need to be able to intercept every request made to maven central.

This is just a POC, I'm not looking for other solutions, I want to create my own.

So, where's the actual documentation of http maven repo?